# Meteor Galaxy starting and stopping

Tags: meteor, galaxy

I am currently working on building a simple online game as practice and to be able to play with some friends. I am interested in the ease of use of the Galaxy system provided by Meteor, but do not want to constantly pay the hourly price, totaling around $30 per month.

They mention that you can stop your which stops billing (on [this](https://www.meteor.com/galaxy-faq) site) but I have yet to find out much more about starting and stopping.

Is there any back end work that needs to be done each time an app is stopped and then started? What is the time delay for starting/stopping? Is there a maximum amount of times an app can be started and stopped per month?

If there is a site that answers all this that I missed in my research, I apologize. I've tried looking everywhere I can.

Answer (score 0):

i have apps hosted on Galaxy, and no i haven't seen anything cumbersome when taking an app offline and back online. it's simply unavailable when offline, and then just starts up when back online.

note that, during this time, i didn't do anything with the database (which is hosted on Mongo's Atlas) until i permanently took an app offline. so the db portion may be a consideration for you.